# Mac Automator conditional workflows

Tags: macos, automator

I'm quite new to Automator on Mac. I'm trying to use it to make a project template creator for Unity. Currently the workflow I have gets a template project folder, duplicates it and allows it to be renamed and will then auto-run the new project in Unity.

I would like it to have a pop up with some checkboxes to further customise the template. These checkboxes would remove/add additional packages to the project stuff like Vuforia, NGUI, etc.

I'm not sure how to do the checkboxes or the conditional workflow if they are even possible to in Automator.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a "Run Applescript" action, that asks which options you want and then builds the list of optional installs (assuming each option is a folder path), which you can then pass that list out of the action and back to the workflow, to copy each of those folders. You could also do the build in Applescript, which is the kind of what AS is designed for.
Something like:

```
set theOptions to {"Vuforia", "NGUI", "Other"}
set theChoices to choose from list theOptions with prompt "Select the options you'd like installed." with multiple selections allowed

set installItems to {}
if theChoices contains "Vuforia" then set installItems to installItems & vuforiaPath
if theChoices contains "NGUI" then set installItems to installItems & NGUIPath
if theChoices contains "Other" then set installItems to installItems & OtherPath
return installItems
```

Your if statements may have to contain more to do, if installation is more than a list of paths to 'also include'. This was just an attempt to get you out of AS and back into Automator as quickly as possible. You can bring up dialogs in Automator, save to a variable, bring up another, etc, but it's clunky.